# How do you arrange shapes in Adobe Illustrator to mimic someone holding cards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I'm having a hard time placing square shapes evenly as if someone was holding playing cards. Is there a feature in Adobe Illustrator that can help me achieve this?[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to GraphicDesign! Can you please edit your question to include more information on your attempts so far? For more detail, check out [this meta post](http://goo.gl/U64omw)

Answer (score 8):

In Illustrator, you when you rotate an object using the rotate tool, you can first click once to set the pivot pint and that's what your object will rotate around.  arrange your cards in a row so that they are not quite on top of each other, and then pivot them all at the same pivot point.

To ensure they are all rotated at the same pivot point, rotate the first card to your desired angle, click the next card and press ctrl+d (cmd+d on mac) to perform the same transformation again.  To achieve the results I've pictured here, increment the number of transforms per card, in other words on the first card you rotate, do it once.  On the second card, do it twice, and so on.

**The key to this effect is the pivot point.**  Keep at it and you'll get the results you want.

[image: Rotated Cards]